# Manage 404 in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am doing the following thing in order to handle 404 error -

```
 <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <>
          <Menubar />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

But that's not showing the not `NotFound` component.

This is my second reactjs app. Sorry for the foolish question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work! React Router’s  component will render the first matched component.This means if the routes above haven’t matched, the only possible solution is hit a route that doesn’t actually exist

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/Menubar " component={Menubar } />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: You've not read my code attentively. My requirement is different.